# Plot categorical data on world map (cartopy/matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, cartopy

I have a dataframe like:

```
latitude    longitude   category
0   -58.5   -26.5   NaN 
1   -55.5   -70.5   ET
2   -55.5   -69.5   ET
3   -55.5   -68.5   ET
4   -55.5   -67.5   ET
```

How can I create a map like the following where the labels are just my categories?

[image]
To plot the coastlines it's just:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
plt.show()
```

But the tutorial for cartopy only mentions heatmap-type data, and even 
 when I convert the categories to numerical (integers) data, I'm not sure how I can go from a numpy array. https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/matplotlib/advanced_plotting.html

My data doesn't cover all the longitude/latitude pairs.

Comment: Is your data irregular or on a grid?

Comment: They're on a grid.

Answer (score 0):

Try `plt.pcolormesh` instead of `plt.contourf`.